# Setting up a complex git alias

Tags: git

I'd like to set up a git alias which, upon `git log` would run

```
git log --pretty=format:"%C(yellow)%h  %C(red)%an, %C(green)%ar %""s" 
           --since=2.weeks –n20
```

I tried running

```
git config --global alias.log 'log --pretty=format:"%C(yellow)%h  
           %C(red)%an, %C(green)%ar %""s" --since=2.weeks –n20'
```

And confirmed that it is recorded in .gitconfig as

```
 28 [alias]
       …
 34   log = log --pretty=format:\"%C(yellow)%h  %C(red)%an,
                 %C(green)%ar %\"\"s\" --since=2.weeks –n20
```

This however does not format git output as expected.

What am I missing please?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From git documentation:

> To avoid confusion and troubles with script usage, aliases that hide
>   existing git commands are ignored.

You'll have to rename your alias.